# Inverse Z transformation in specific points

Tags: inverse, z-transform

I'm given

$$H(z)=\frac{z^4+6z}{z^6+1}$$

and I need to find $h(k)$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$.

Where $H(z)$ is the Z transformation of $h(k)$.

Since H is very complicated, I believe some trick could be used to calculate only $h(k)$ for the specific values. Or do I need to calculate the whole inverse transformation? I could use some help either way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is expand the denominator in a geometric series, and multiply by the numerator.  You get

$$H(z) = z^{-6} (z^4+6 z) (1-z^{-6}+z^{-12}-\cdots) = z^{-2} + 6 z^{-5}-z^{-8}-\cdots$$

The $h[k]$ are just the coefficients of $z^{-k}$ this expansion, so you can read them right off, i.e., $h[0]=h[1]=0$, $h[2]=1$, etc.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that $h[-1]=6$, etc? Since in the original transformation is defined $H(z)=\sum{h(k)z^{-k}}$

Comment: @Mugen: Yep.  Easy fix though.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: I now have $H(z)=\frac{1}{z^3+3z+1}$, representing it as the sum of a geometric series isn't very simple. What do you recommend?

Comment: OK, I understood how to do that too. Nice tricks :)